# What's the correct way to build up a file path from multiple strings?

Tags: c#, filepath

Here's how I'm currently building a file path from multiple strings (actual names and values from my code have been replaced for the purpose of this question).

```
const string STATIC_PART_OF_PATH = "/";

var topLevel = string.Join("/","A","B","C","D");          // "A/B/C/D"

string node1 = string.Format("{0}/Node1", topLevel);      // "A/B/C/D/Node1"
string node2 = topLevel + STATIC_PART_OF_PATH + "Node2";  // "A/B/C/D/Node2"
string node3 = topLevel + STATIC_PART_OF_PATH + "Node3";  // "A/B/C/D/Node3"
```

I am unsure if this is the best convention/practice.

What's the correct way to build up a full string path?

Comment: @GrantWinney unsure of what i am asking or what the code above is trying to do? what i am asking for is it best convention to use the structure above i.e. string.Join and string combining for constructing paths. It seems you and Eldar have provided the solution in Path.Combine. Thanks

Comment: For my own future reference, is this question down voted as it is not a decent question or the format of the question is not good?

Comment: Thanks - i can see how the question is not very clear and i have not presented it well. The STATIC_PART_OF_PATH was saved too quickly - should have be a sub path e.g. '/F/G/'. Unfortunately Path.Combine generates '\\' where as this was for a third party tool which requires '/'; again not clear in my question. I was attempting to present different solutions i.e. join, format, or '+'. Thank for you taking the time to comment and help my improve my stack overflow participation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way of building filesystem path is to use `Path.Combine`, even for string literals.

```
var path = Path.Combine("ABCD", "Node1", "Node2", "Node3");
```

Anyway, paths containing both "\" and "/" should work correctly, but *canonical* way is of course `Path.Combine`.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the answer and will refactor the project to use this